# groupby when column contains multi-dimensional array that needs to be added

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 2 dimensional vector as a column. I would like to groupby one of the columns and add the vectors up.

I have tried groupby then sum as shown in the code below, but the output column is adding dimensions to the vector rather than adding the vectors (similarly to when using np.add).

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['A', 'B', 'A'], 'label2' : ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                     'output' :   [[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] ,[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]],[[17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24]]] })

data_grouped = data.groupby('label')['output'].sum()
```

I would like to groupby 'label' and have the outputs aggregated. Given that the output is two dimensional vector, i would like the vectors to be added and not combined. Therfore, my expectation is to have:

```
label A: output is [[18,20,22,24],[26,28,30,32]]
label B: output is [[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

but I am getting:

```
label A: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [17, 18, 19, 20],[21,22,23,24]]

label B: [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The solution

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['A', 'B', 'A'], 'label2' : ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                     'output' :   [[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] ,[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]],[[17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24]]] })

data['output'] = data['output'].map(np.array)
data_grouped = data[['label', 'output']].groupby('label').sum()
print(data_group)

>>>                                      output
>>> label                                      
>>> A      [[18, 20, 22, 24], [26, 28, 30, 32]]
>>> B       [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

#### The explanation

Your `output` contains python lists. Operation `+` on 2 lists concatenates the lists together:

```py
print([1, 2] + [3, 4])
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]

print([[1], [2]] + [[3], [4]])
>>> [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

`data['output'].map(np.array)` turns your 2D lists into 2D numpy arrays. Numpy arrays `+` operation (which is used by `sum()`) sums the values that are on "the same place" in both arrays.